# GODOT 4 | Navigation path gets lost

Tags: game-development, path-finding, godot

For some reason, the enemy, when following the player, can change the path for a second to some corner or somewhere else. Because of this, he sometimes twitches and goes back. What could be the problem? Here is my code

```
extends CharacterBody2D
class_name Ghosts

@onready var region_id: RID = NavigationServer2D.region_create()

var path:Array = []
var nav:NavigationRegion2D = null
var player = null

func _ready():
    await get_tree()
    var tree = get_tree()
    if tree.has_group("LevelNavigation"):
        nav = tree.get_nodes_in_group("LevelNavigation")[0]
        NavigationServer2D.region_set_map(region_id, get_world_2d().navigation_map)
        NavigationServer2D.region_ser_navpoly(region_id, nav.navpoly)
    if tree.has_group("Player"):
        player = tree.get_nodes_in_group("Player")[0]

func attack(speed:int):
    if path.size() > 0:
        velocity = global_position.direction_to(path[1]) * speed
        if global_position == path[0]:
            path.pop_front()
    move_and_slide()

func generate_path(line2D: Line2D):
    if nav != null and player != null:
        path = NavigationServer2D.map_get_path(get_world_2d().navigation_map, position
        line2D.points = path
```

[image: Enemy wrong path]

I would like to get the correct path. Maybe it's the features of Godot 4

Answer (score 1):

### Noop

First this is nothing:

```
await get_tree()
```

The method `get_tree` is not asynchronous, and you are discarding the result anyway. Perhaps you wanted to `await` for the `Node` to enter the scene tree? That would be `await self.tree_entered`… Except you have the line inside `_ready` and when Godot calls `_ready` the `Node` is inside the tree (which also means it will not enter, so waiting for it to enter won't work).

*Just remove that line.*

---

### Following the path

Second this won't work well:

```
if path.size() > 0:
    velocity = global_position.direction_to(path[1]) * speed
    if global_position == path[0]:
        path.pop_front()
move_and_slide()
```

1. You are moving towards `path[1]` and not `path[0]`
2. Even if you were, nothing is preventing you from overshooting.
3. Even if you were preventing overshooting, the equality comparison won't work well due to floating point errors.

---

So the plan:

- If there are no points in the path, we are done.
- If there are points in the path, pick the first point.
- If the current position is close enough to the point, remove it.
- Otherwise move towards the point.

Let us do it:

```
if path.empty():
    return

var point := path[0]
if global_position.distance_to(point) <= threshold:
    path.pop_front()
    return

velocity = global_position.direction_to(point) * speed
move_and_slide()
```

Ok, caveats:

- We need to prevent overshooting.
- How much is the threshold?
- When we remove we don't move.

Let us fix that. We need to figure out, beforehand, much we have to move:

```
var distance_to_move := speed * delta
```

But we should not advance more than the distance to the point!

```
if path.empty():
    return

var point:Vector2 = path[0]
var distance_to_point := global_position.distance_to(point)
var distance_to_move := min(speed * delta, distance_to_point)
```

And the velocity will be that to move that in this frame:

```
if path.empty():
    return

var point:Vector2 = path[0]
var distance_to_point := global_position.distance_to(point)
var direction_to_point := global_position.direction_to(point) 
var distance_to_move := minf(speed * delta, distance_to_point)

if distance_to_point <= distance_to_move:
    path.pop_front()

velocity = direction_to_point * (distance_to_move / delta)
move_and_slide()
```

This way we don't overshoot, we move even when we remove, and we have a clear threshold for removing.

Caveats:

- We don't always move the full distance.

For that we need a loop:

```
var total_distance_to_move := speed * delta
while total_distance_to_move > 0.0 and not path.empty():
    var point:Vector2 = path[0]
    var distance_to_point := global_position.distance_to(point)
    var direction_to_point := global_position.direction_to(point) 
    var distance_to_move := minf(total_distance_to_move, distance_to_point)

    if distance_to_point <= distance_to_move:
        path.pop_front()

    velocity = direction_to_point * (distance_to_move / delta)
    move_and_slide()

    total_distance_to_move -= distance_to_move
```

---

### Generating the path

The code is cut off where you use `map_get_path`, however I can see you are using `position`.

Work with the `global_position` instead:

```
path = Navigation2DServer.map_get_path(
    get_world_2d().get_navigation_map(),
    global_position,
    target_pos,
    true
)
```

*I don't know how you were getting the target position, but I'll trust you can figure out how to make it with global coordinates.*

---

And you are setting this to a `Line2D`. That wants its own local coordinantes. So you do this:

```
line2d.points = line2d.global_transform.affine_inverse() * path
```